# All requests to a Places service must use the https:// protocol, and include an API key

Tags: javascript, http, axios

Whenever I make an axios GET request to Google's Places API, I get an error:

```
"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource."
```

I checked the documentation of Google's Place API and found this:

```
"Each of the services is accessed as an HTTP request, and returns either an JSON or 
XML response. All requests to a Places service must use the https:// protocol, and 
include an API key."
```

Am I understanding correctly that in order for me to use that API, the request must come from a hosted website with domain name and SSL certificate so that I can have a https:// protocol?

I'm currently working on http://localhost:8080/#/. Is there a way for me to use this API so I can develop my app without using hosting at this point?

Comment: `Am I understanding correctly` no ... it's saying all requests must use https and must include an API key - the CORS thing suggests, that yes, requests must come from a server, not a browser, but the server doesn't have to "serve" https, it just has to make the request using https

Comment: So I need back-end using a server-side language like PHP or Node.js to make the requests?

Comment: yes, exactly right

Comment: So in my case if I want to get the data from that API, I'd need to make a request from my server to the google API and then make a request from my Vue.js front-end to my own server?

Comment: yes, that's right too

Comment: Thanks, if you want you can submit that as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that documentation is saying is

> all requests must use https and must include an API key

the CORS thing suggests,

> requests must come from a server, not a browser,

That doesn't mean the server has to be a https server, it just has to make requests for that API using HTTPS